# PHP form > JS OnUpdate > AJAX > should return MySQLi data, but I don't understand the code

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I take no credit for the JS or AJAX code and I don't understand it. (Thank you [Alon Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6338083/alon-alexander))
I have no AJAX knowledge and **I would rather use PHP/JS with no JQuery**, but I don't understand how to make it work.

I have a form that uses OnUpdate to fire a JS code that then uses AJAX to perform a SQLi query that should return the search data.

Problem is the return is alway the same even if I use data I KNOW should be returned true (file already exists), but Always returns 'New Entry' in my "Notice" Paragraph

Further, if record found I will then use JS to update form fields with record data. But that is for the next step in this. First need this to work.

i.e. "Record Exists" and form populates with that record info
  or "New Entry" and forms stays blank.

**index.php** //reduced to needed info only

```
<?php include("process.php"); ?>

<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/phone.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/entrynum.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <?php 
    if (isset($_POST['reg-submit'])) {
        echo "<p id='notice' style='padding: .5em; border: 2px solid red;'>Entry $entrynum Saved!<br>$timenow on $datenow</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p id='notice' style='display: none; padding: .5em; border: 2px solid red;'></p>";
    }
    ?>

    <main>
        <div class="Container">
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend><h1>Registration</h1></legend>
                    <label for="entrynum">Entry Number</label>
                    <input type="number" pattern="\d*" name="entrynum" id="entrynum" value="" required="true" placeholder="" autofocus onchange="entry_check()" />

                    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="" required="true" placeholder="" list="" style="text-transform:capitalize" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.value.substr(1);" />

                    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" value="" required="true" placeholder="" list="" style="text-transform:capitalize" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.value.substr(1);" />

                    <input type="submit" name="reg-submit" id="reg-submit" value="Submit" />
                </fieldset> <!-- Registration Form-->
            </form>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

**entrynum.js**

```
function entry_check() {

var entrynum = $("#entrynum").val();

// Send the AJAX call
$.post(
    'entrysearch.php', // TO search.php page
    {entrynum: entrynum}, // the DATA sent with the request
    function(data) { // a CALLBACK function
        if (data == 'none') { // no rows were found or an error occurred
            document.getElementById("notice").innerHTML = "New Entry!";
            document.getElementById("notice").style.display = "block";
            return;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("notice").innerHTML = "Already Exists!";
            document.getElementById("notice").style.display = "block";
        }
    }
);

}
```

**entrysearch.php**

```
<?php
include("includes/connect.php");

if (!isset($_POST['entrynum'])) {
    echo 'none';
    die();
}
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM HeatWaveData WHERE entrynum=%d", $_POST['entrynum']);
$results = $db->query($sql);
$result = $results[0];
if (!$result) {
    echo 'none';
    die();
}
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and also have an SQL syntax error, causing your query to fail, return boolean false, and then you propagate the failure further, causing `$result` to be false as well,

Comment: Or maybe not an sql syntax error, but unless you have some custom wrapper around pdo or mysqli, your prepare call is not a valid `prepare` call at all.

Comment: @MarcB I don't need a prepared statement at all really. This is a password protected site and only a couple users so injection risk very low. I can add protections lated once I figure out what I'm doing. I tried removing the prepare but got even more errors...

Comment: @DanielYantis: Exactly the WRONG attitude to have. even if the "attack" isn't malicious. you're still stuffing user-provided input directly into a query. go ahead and enjoy your system barfing all over itself when you implement a name-based search with `... where name='Miles O'Brien';`

Comment: @MarcB : I get your point and I'll work on it. I'm a total noob with JS and AJAX. I kinda get PHP a little more and I am ok with HTML in general. But please explain "unless you have some custom wrapper around pdo or mysqli, your prepare call is not a valid prepare call at all". I didn't write this code and I don't get the prepared statement

Comment: well, if that DB library is just plain pdo or mysqli, then the prepare call syntax is completely wrong. there is no `%d`-type formatting chars in a prepare call. there's `?` and `:whatever` for placeholders, which are not formatting chars.

Comment: @DanielYantis The main thing you need to do differently is `$('form').on('change', '#entrynum', function(e){` and rework the AJAX logic to suit your needs.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus : the whole "rework the AJAX logic to suit your needs" is where I can't continue. I don't know AJAX! can this be done with just plain JS / PHP and not jquery?

Comment: `'entrynum'` is a **STRING**. It's not a field identifiers. field/table identifers are never quoted as strings, because once they're strings, they're not identifiers. you're basically saying "if string with letters e, n, t, etc.. has the value 777". `WHERE entrynum = 777` would work. "if (field named 'entrynum has value 777)"

Comment: @MarcB : yes, I was using backtics but when pasted here I used single quotes. It is backtics in the actual code.

Comment: well, this is getting WAYYYY too long. You really need to learn how to do basic PHP debugging. Start adding tracking output. see what happens at every stage of the script. Narrow down WHERE your problem(s) are occuring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY! It seems the sql needed a var ($entry) instead of using $_POST['entrynum']... Not sure why.

Then if no records found the ajax would not return anything (not even NULL). So I had to add some if statements and return '0' if no records found.

Further, it helped to add datatype "json' so object was parsed.

Javascript:

```
function entry_check() {
    var entrynum = $("#entrynum").val();
    $.post(
        'entrysearch.php',
        {entrynum: entrynum},
        function(data) {
            if (!data) {
                document.getElementById("notice").innerHTML = "New Entry!";
                document.getElementById("notice").style.display = "block";

            } else {
                document.getElementById("notice").innerHTML = "Already Exists!";
                document.getElementById("notice").style.display = "block";
            }
        }, "json"
    );
}
```

entrysearch.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['entrynum'])) {
    $entry = $_POST['entrynum'];
    include("connect.php");
    $sql = ("SELECT * FROM HeatWaveData WHERE entrynum = $entry");
    if ($results=mysqli_query($db,$sql)) {
        if ($rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($results)) {
            $result = $results->fetch_object();
            echo json_encode($result);
        } else {
            echo $rowcount;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

It works! Took me all night of research reading examples and docs.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use $.ajax function instead of post.

You can try by adding an id to the form by adding `id="myform"`, then change entrynum.js as it follows:

```
    // Change onSubmit behaviour for the form
    $("#myform").on("submit", function(e) {
        // Prevent page reload
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            // Get form action or uses current page.
            url : $(this).attr('action') || window.location.pathname,
            type: "POST",
            // Get all input to submit and serialize on array (this will become $_POST)
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                //Here you have server response
            },
            error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // If error thrown jXHR contains XMLHttpRequest stuff like status
                console.log(jXHR);
                // You will see on an alert the real error thrown
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Again, I'm still learning! But I'm going to need the returned record data for my next step in this... OnUpdate with report if record exists and then I will need the record data to display that record info in the form fields.